# Can I simulate that my MySql field is an array

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I simulate that my MySQL field is an array, and later with some query to search element in that array ?

Comment: Assuming you could, what sort of scenario did you have in mind for using it?

Comment: One way to handle this would be, to manage it manually in your server. (Example: Django saves the value as a comma separated string, and when retrieved, splits on `,` and returns the array) - You can do that too

Comment: @DanBrauk I have subjects in some school, and every subject have 4,5 professors with access of his materials. When some professor is logged , i need to know what subjects are that.

Comment: Show an example of the data and relations. You probably want to store the possible values of that "array" in another table and use a join table to manage relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In only MySql:
To get the field.

```
select FIELDNAME from TABLE
```

To search from that result set:

```
select FIELDNAME from TABLE where FIELDNAME like '%myvalue%'
```

The %'s are wild cards. This would return any value with myvalue in it.
Such as:
(amyvalue, bmyvalueb, I<3myvaluecompletely)

If you want this done in some language you need to provide a more verbose and detailed question.

Comment: I use PHP, MySQL combination

Comment: So you would like to return all values from a field into an array? Or do you want only matching values into an array. Could you please rephrase your question.

Comment: But this works fantastic, just put %,arrayfield,%  .  Just put field as a VARCHAR